# Difference between numpad-9 key and G-Key when using SendMessage

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I am using JNA to send inputs to a unreal engine game. I want to type "G" and "Numpad9" every 5 seconds to the game, but for some reason the "Numpad9" doesn't work although "G" works perfectly, so there must be a difference between those keys. Can anyone tell me what I can do to make it work?

**EDIT:** The game should not must have focus while receiving the inputs!

If someone needs it, here is the code I use:

```
public class DDAutostartWave
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        DDConnection.findRightHandle();
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DDConnection.typeKey(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            DDConnection.typeKey(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9);
            DDConnection.typeKey(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9);
        }
    }
}

public class DDConnection
{
    private static HWND rightWindowHandle;
    private static User32 USER = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    public static void typeKey(int key)
    {
        try
        {
            pressKey(key);
            Thread.sleep(3);
            releaseKey(key);
            Thread.sleep(3);
        } catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void pressKey(int key)
    {
        WinDef.WPARAM wparam = new WinDef.WPARAM(key);
        WinDef.LPARAM lparam = new WinDef.LPARAM(1 + (USER.MapVirtualKey(key, 0) << 16));
        USER.SendMessageA(rightWindowHandle, 0x0100, wparam, lparam);
    }

    public static void releaseKey(int key)
    {
        WinDef.WPARAM wparam = new WinDef.WPARAM(key);
        WinDef.LPARAM lparam = new WinDef.LPARAM(1 + (USER.MapVirtualKey(key, 0) << 16) + (1 << 30) + (1 << 31));
        USER.SendMessageA(rightWindowHandle, 0x0101, wparam, lparam);
    }

    public static boolean findRightHandle()
    {
        rightWindowHandle = USER.FindWindow(null, "Dungeon Defenders");
        if(rightWindowHandle == null) return false;

        System.out.println(rightWindowHandle);
        return true;
    }
}

interface User32 extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32
{
    int MapVirtualKey(int ucode, int uMapType);
    void SendMessageA(HWND handle, int message, WinDef.WPARAM wparam, WinDef.LPARAM lparam);
}
```

Comment: Numpad keys require special handling in `SendMessage()`; the key codes may overlap with others under certain unpredictable conditions. But that's beside the point. Do not use `SendMessage()` to fake input. Use `SendInput()` instead.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work with  `SendInput()` either. Any other idea?

Comment: For `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP`, you are setting `lParam` to 0 for both messages. Call [`MapVirtualKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306.aspx) to get the scan code for each virtual key and specify that scan code in bits 16-23 of `lParam`. For `WM_KEYUP`, you also need to set bits 0-15 to a numeric value of 1 for the repeat count, and set bits 30 and 31 to 1 for the previous key state and transition state, respectively. That being said, do use `SendInput()` instead. If you are having trouble with it, you are likely using it wrong. Show your latest code.

Comment: Blog entry with information on why `SendMessage` (or `PostMessage`) won't work, as explained in the comments above: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: thanks for the link. I think I missed something in my question: I want to send inputs to it while it doesn't have focus and I am not sure if this is possible with `SendInput()`. I also updated my code according to your instructions, but it still doesn't work(for new code, see above). Could it be that the problem is that the game maybe uses `GetKeyState()` when looking for the numpad keys instead of the same method it uses for "G"? Is there a way to make the game think those keys are down although it doesn't have the focus?